# Navbar Always displayed behind images from carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried using z-index, so that my navbar would appear over my carousel images... but to no avail. I think the reason it is not working is because it is not static.

The way I have it set up is so that when the user scrolls down, the navbar gradually disappears, when the user user scrolls up the navbar gradually appears. Whether this is interfering with the z-index.. I'm not sure. Any help is much appreciated.

The following is my **HTML FOR NAVBAR**:

```
<header class="nav-down">
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fnt navbar-backgrnd center">
  <div class="container-fluid navbar-inner">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SMcD</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Me
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Seanie Mc</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The following is my **HTML FOR CAROUSEL**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="{% static 'personal/img/seanie1.jpg' %}" alt="Chania">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="{% static 'personal/img/seanie2.jpg' %}" alt="Chania">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="{% static 'personal/img/seanie3.jpg' %}" alt="Flower">
  </div>
</div>

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>

<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
```

There is alot more css, than what I am giving. But the rest is mainly changing the colors displayed when items on the navbar are clicked etc...

The Following is my **CSS**:

```
.navbar{
  z-index: 2;
}

.carousel-inner{
  z-index: 1;
}
```

The Following is my **JS**:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myCarousel").carousel();

    $(".item").click(function(){
      $("#myCarousel").carousel(1);
    });

    $(".left").click(function(){
      $("#myCarousel").carousel("prev");
    });
  });

  var didScroll;
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  var delta = 5;
  var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

  $(window).scroll(function(event){
      didScroll = true;
  });

  setInterval(function() {
      if (didScroll) {
          hasScrolled();
          didScroll = false;
      }
  }, 250);

  function hasScrolled() {
      var st = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) {
          return;
      }
      if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight)  {
          $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
      } else {
          if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
              $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
          }
      }
      lastScrollTop = st;
  }
```

Comment: So you want navbar to be shown always ?

Comment: yes, always taking priority over other elements on my page!

Comment: in the HTML, theres a closing </header> missing at the end... for anyone confused :P

Comment: It works fine. I dont find navbar moving. http://jsbin.com/xelatol/edit?html,output what is the issue in this

Comment: trying to make a mock up on JS Bin now of my version... there is a difference between mine and yours... it will show

Comment: http://jsbin.com/dinozirewi/edit?output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show navbar in the top give higher z-index than carousel.

```
header {
  z-index: 100
}
```

Comment: The navbar is appearing above the image now, but the navbar is not moving up when i scroll down and down when i scroll up, like it does in the original jsbin link i gave you. :(

Comment: We're getting close though :P

Comment: Almost, but in gaining this feature you have removed the functionality of when the user scrolls down the majority of navbar disappears, likewise when the user scrolls up the whole navbar reappears. The original problem was that the navbar was not appearing over the image when the navbar was scrolled up at somepoint.

Comment: In your code, I didnt observe any such issue when i scroll up.

Comment: when you scroll down does the navbar disappear, and then when you scroll up does it reappear? That is original functionality that I want to keep. I also want the navbar to take priority over the image, which you have done in the link you gave me. But you also got rid of the functionality where the navbar dynamically moves up and down when the user scrolls up and down.

Comment: You can see the original functionality in the original link... http://jsbin.com/huhegog/edit?output     ............ I want to keep that functionality but also have it so that when the user scrolls down you can still see the small bit of navbar left over the image.

Comment: You didnt need to add navbar-fixed-top class to navbar. It works now!